# Angular Sort by button click

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Hey so i'm a beginner trying to understand angularjs/typescript.

I've got an array of fruits written in an unordered list in which i want to sort by descending order and reverse search it in alphabetic order via a button. However I don't know what the function should like... Any help is appriciated

Html:

```js
export class AppComponent {
  fruits: string[] = ["Apple", "Banana", "Orange", "Peach", "Pear", ];
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let fruits of fruits">{{fruits}}
  </li>
</ul>

<button ng-click="send()">Sort </button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use sort() function.

```
 send(){
    this.fruits = this.fruits.sort((n1,n2) => {
    if (n1 < n2) {
        return 1;
    }

    if (n1 > n2) {
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
});
  }
```

This is the link to your solution. [stackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-aaoo8b?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Doesn't work for me... I do not get any results when I press the button

Comment: Oh my bad, oh cool thanks dude! Would it be possible to make the button after it has been clicked once to sort in order again?

Comment: sort  back to ascending order?

Comment: Yes sort of like a toggle function, or is that possible?

Comment: what if we use 2 buttons for 2 purposes?

Comment: That is def possible, but I'd like to see it via one button like a toggle function

Comment: Wow that's a smart solution! Thank you so much for helping me out, super patient!!

Answer (score 1):

Ok fruits where is?

Anyway:

```
export class AppComponent {
  cities: string[] = [ "Pear","Banana", "Apple", "Orange", "Peach" ];
}
```

Ok, now

```
  <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let city of cities">{{city}}
      </li>
    </ul>

    <button (click)="send()">Sort </button>
```

And use the function:

```
send(){
    this.cities = this.cities.sort(); 
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. Nothing is still happening when I click the button hm

Comment: try to add this : (click), so <button (click)="send()">Sort </button>

Comment: Holy cow! Thank you so much! Thank you for being so patient with me! Now how would I go on If I would want the button to change the order all around? So it goes from descending to ascending order? (Sorry for bomarding you with questions :D)

Answer (score 0):

change the `sort()` so that it sorts string.

```
 send(){
     this.fruits.sort((n1,n2) => {
  return n1.localeCompare(n2)  
});
```

take a look at the stackblitz example, [stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mmt2yh?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

To toggle, 
set a variable, check the variable and return the value.

```
send(){
    this.order = !this.order;
     this.fruits.sort((n1,n2) => {       
      return (this.order)? n1.localeCompare(n2):n2.localeCompare(n1);
    });
  }
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply, this def works. Would it be possible to make the button work as a toggle function sorting them in different orders ascending to descending etc

Comment: @Durutelefon1 I have updated the code, you may check now.